# How to go to previous commits in eclipse and egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have a git android project managed in eclipse and some times i want to temporarily roll back my android project to a specific time and then build it and do stuff and then restore to the latest version.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To check out an old state:

1. Open the *History* view for the repository (Window > Show view > Other... > Team > History)
2. Select the commit at the time you want
3. Context menu > *Checkout*

When you want to go back, just select the commit where master is (or the branch you were working on before) and select *Checkout* again. Because there is a branch there, it will automatically check out the branch instead of the commit.

Note that you may also have to enable "Show All Branches and Tags" in the history to see master in the history view, see the [section in the user guide about this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#All_Branches).

Comment: Hi, I often used this way, but now I can't find my commit hash in the history. I activated "Show all branches and tags" and "Show all changes in repo..." but the commit hash is not found.

When I checkout by commit hash manually the history instantly shows the commit?! oO
Any idea why the history does not show all commits?