# Extract PNG File from Eclipse Git Commit

Tags: eclipse, extract, commit, egit

Several months ago, I committed some code and files to the local Git Repository in Eclipse IDE.  I did not push the changes to the central Git Repository.  Later, I deleted those files and committed those changes again to the local Git Repository in Eclipse IDE.  Now, I need those files again.  So, I open the `Git Reflog` tab in Eclipse IDE.  I scrolled down to the commit and double-click on it.  This opens another tab showing me the message I wrote, the files and the branches.  Here's a screenshot of the files.

[image: Committed Files]

If I double-click on a text file, an editor opens with the contents of the file.  This is exactly what I need.  However, if I double-click on the `png` file, an editor opens which shows me the textual representation of the bytes in the file.  This isn't what I need.  How do I get the actual file?

In another commit, the only files in the commit were images.  So, I `Cherry Pick`ed them back into my branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out one can checkout a commit, copy the files to temporary location, checkout the local branch, and then copy the files from the temporary location back into the branch.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200282/294317) explains how do to the checkout.